# Newtonsoft JObject not accepted as JSONObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have to create a `JSONObject` and give it to one of my functions.
I use `Newtonsoft` to try to create a `JSONObject` which should be `JObject` if I am correct.

This is how my code looks right now:

```
public void GetLogindata() {
    Debug.Log(loginInputfield.text + " -- " + passwordInputfield.text);
    networkmanager.SendLoginData(JObject.FromObject(new Logindata(loginInputfield.text,passwordInputfield.text));
}
```

I think I am able to create the `JObject` but my compiler tells me:

> Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'JSONObject'

Btw, I am using `socket.io` for `unity` if that helps, maybe its the function itself or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: No, that is not correct.  JObject is part of Json.Net, which has nothing to do with Socket.IO for Unity.   I'm guessing that Socket.IO for Unity has its own JSONObject, and that is what you need to use here.

Comment: I normally parse from JRaw. Try breaking your code up into separate steps and be explicit in declaring your variables.

Comment: I agree w/ @BrianRogers, the object types are different. What is returned from `Logindata` constructor?

Comment: @RobScott I think the right question is: what type is expected as first parameter for `SendLoginData`?

Comment: I could answer Rob Scott's question, it is Logindata; and thepirat000's question, it is JSONObject. Isn't it obvious?